# Multi-Color Gradient Fade for Text without CSS?

Tags: php, colors, hex, rgb, linear-gradients

I'd like help getting this PHP function to work with a third color option.

Note: No CSS. No Javascript. Just PHP and HTML.

```
<?php

function Gradient($HexFrom, $HexTo, $ColorSteps)
{
        $FromRGB['r'] = hexdec(substr($HexFrom, 0, 2));
        $FromRGB['g'] = hexdec(substr($HexFrom, 2, 2));
        $FromRGB['b'] = hexdec(substr($HexFrom, 4, 2));

        $ToRGB['r'] = hexdec(substr($HexTo, 0, 2));
        $ToRGB['g'] = hexdec(substr($HexTo, 2, 2));
        $ToRGB['b'] = hexdec(substr($HexTo, 4, 2));

        $StepRGB['r'] = ($FromRGB['r'] - $ToRGB['r']) / ($ColorSteps - 1);
        $StepRGB['g'] = ($FromRGB['g'] - $ToRGB['g']) / ($ColorSteps - 1);
        $StepRGB['b'] = ($FromRGB['b'] - $ToRGB['b']) / ($ColorSteps - 1);

        $GradientColors = array();

        for($i = 0; $i <= $ColorSteps; $i++)
        {
                $RGB['r'] = floor($FromRGB['r'] - ($StepRGB['r'] * $i));
                $RGB['g'] = floor($FromRGB['g'] - ($StepRGB['g'] * $i));
                $RGB['b'] = floor($FromRGB['b'] - ($StepRGB['b'] * $i));

                $HexRGB['r'] = sprintf('%02x', ($RGB['r']));
                $HexRGB['g'] = sprintf('%02x', ($RGB['g']));
                $HexRGB['b'] = sprintf('%02x', ($RGB['b']));

                $GradientColors[] = implode(NULL, $HexRGB);
        }
        return $GradientColors;
}

$text = "blah testing blah testing blah";
$length = strlen($text);
$Gradients = Gradient("00FF00", "0000FF", $length);

for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
    echo '<span style="color: #' . $Gradients[$i] . ';">' . $text[$i] . '</span>';
}


?>
```

What must I do to get a 3rd option? Such as:

```
Gradient($HexOne, $HexTwo, $HexThree, $ColorSteps)
                         //^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php#93920 Looks like somebody made some headway with a four color gradient 5 years ago. Perhaps this document will be of use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

So basically what I just added is, that if you provide more than 2 colors, that it simply merges the first gradient with the next one until you have all gradients which you want together. It also allows you to have different steps for each gradient which you have. So you can define that it should go from green to red in 20 steps and from red to blue in 50 steps.

You can either pass the colors as array and the steps as array or integer when you take an instance of the class. Or you can use the methods `setColors()` to set the array of colors and `setSteps()` to set the array or integer as interval.

You can also define if the gradient should be chunked or not if you have multiple colors. You can set  and get the value if it should get chunked with `setChunkedGradientState()` and `getChunkedGradientState()`. This simply means if you don't want the gradient chunked, which is the default value, you will get an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => FD9B09
    [1] => EBAE1C
    [2] => D9C230
    [3] => C7D544
    [4] => B6E958
    [5] => B6E958
    [6] => A9EC8D
    [7] => 9CEFC2
    [8] => 8FF2F8
)
```

If it should be chunked you will get an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => FD9B09
            [1] => EBAE1C
            [2] => D9C230
            [3] => C7D544
            [4] => B6E958
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => B6E958
            [1] => A9EC8D
            [2] => 9CEFC2
            [3] => 8FF2F8
        )
)
```

full code:

```
<?php


    class Gradienter {

        public $colors = [];
        public $gradient = [];
        public $colorSteps = 2;
        public $chunkedGradient = FALSE;

        public function __construct(array $colors = [], $colorSteps = 2, $chunkedGradient = FALSE) {
            $this->setColors($colors);
            $this->setSteps($colorSteps);
            $this->setChunkedGradientState($chunkedGradient);

            return $this;   
        }


        public function getGradient() {

            if(count($this->colors) == 2) {
                $this->createSingleGradient();
            } elseif(count($this->colors) > 2) {
                $this->createMultipleGradient();
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Not enough colors provided");
            }

            if($this->chunkedGradient)
                $this->getChunkedGradient();

            return $this->gradient;

        }

        public function getChunkedGradient() {

            $stepCount = count($this->colors) - 1;
            for($count = 0; $count < $stepCount; $count++) {
                if(!is_array($this->colorSteps))
                    $gradient[] = array_splice($this->gradient, 0, $this->colorSteps);
                elseif(!isset($this->colorSteps[$count]))
                    $gradient[] = array_splice($this->gradient, 0, 2);
                else
                    $gradient[] = array_splice($this->gradient, 0, $this->colorSteps[$count]);
            }
            $this->gradient = $gradient;

        }

        public function createSingleGradient() {

            if(!is_array($this->colorSteps))
                $this->$gradient = $this->createGradient($this->colors[0], $this->colors[1], $this->colorSteps);
            else
                $this->$gradient = $this->createGradient($this->colors[0], $this->colors[1], $this->colorSteps[0]);

        }

        public function createMultipleGradient() {

            foreach($this->colors as $k => $color) {
                if(!isset($this->colors[$k+1]))
                    break;

                if(!is_array($this->colorSteps))
                    $this->gradient = array_merge($this->gradient, $this->createGradient($this->colors[$k], $this->colors[$k+1], $this->colorSteps));
                elseif(isset($this->colorSteps[$k]))
                    $this->gradient = array_merge($this->gradient, $this->createGradient($this->colors[$k], $this->colors[$k+1], $this->colorSteps[$k]));
                else
                    $this->gradient = array_merge($this->gradient, $this->createGradient($this->colors[$k], $this->colors[$k+1], 2));

            }

        }

        public function createGradient($start, $end, $interval) {
            $colors = ["r", "g", "b"];
            list($colorStart["r"], $colorStart["g"], $colorStart["b"]) = array_map("hexdec", str_split($start, 2));
            list($colorEnd["r"], $colorEnd["g"], $colorEnd["b"]) = array_map("hexdec", str_split($end, 2));

            foreach($colors as $color)
                $colorSteps[$color] = ($colorStart[$color] - $colorEnd[$color]) / ($interval - 1);

            for($count = 0; $count < $interval; $count++) {
                foreach($colors as $color)
                    $rgb[$color] = floor($colorStart[$color] - ($colorSteps[$color] * $count));

                    $hexRgb = array_combine($colors, array_map(function($v){
                        return substr(sprintf('%02X', $v), 0, 2);
                    }, $rgb));

                    $GradientColors[] = implode("", $hexRgb);
            }

            return $GradientColors;     

        }

        public function setColors(array $colors = []) {
            $this->colors = $colors;
            return $this;
        }

        public function getColors() {
            return $this->colors;
        }

        public function setSteps($colorSteps = 2) {
            if(!is_array($colorSteps))
                $this->setSingleColorSteps($colorSteps);
            else
                $this->setMultipleColorSteps($colorSteps);
            return $this;
        }

        public function setSingleColorSteps($colorSteps) {
            $this->colorSteps = intval($colorSteps < 2 ? 2 : $colorSteps);
        }

        public function setMultipleColorSteps($colorSteps) {
            $this->colorSteps = array_map(function($v){
                    return intval($v < 2 ? 2 : $v);
            }, $colorSteps);
        }

        public function getSteps() {
            return $this->colorSteps;
        }

        public function setChunkedGradientState($chunkedGradient) {
            $this->chunkedGradient = $chunkedGradient;
            return $this;
        }

        public function getChunkedGradientState() {
            return $this->chunkedGradient;
        }


    }





    $gradienter = new Gradienter();
    $gradienter->setColors(["FD9B09", "B6E958", "F2F90B", "8FF2F8", "FB8CF8", "F05C3E"]);
    $gradienter->setSteps([5, 30, 25, 60, 40]);

    $gradients = $gradienter->getGradient();

    foreach($gradients as $k => $color)
        echo "<div style='background-color:#" . $color . "'>" . $color . "</div>";


?>
```

[<kbd>**Demo 1**</kbd>](http://viper-7.com/WA9PGm)
[<kbd>**Demo 2**</kbd>](http://viper-7.com/AcwZo1)